# Numbered enum vs UnNumbered enum

Tags: c#

Given these two enums:

```
public enum test
{
    one = 1,
    two,
    three
}

public enum test2
{
    zero = 0,
    one = 1,
    two = 2,
    three = 3
}
```

I prefer to use the first method. I see many open source projects and code at my job use the second method where every item has a value. I rarely see the first example ever coded. Is there a reason for this? Why is the second approach preferred over the first? Also, you can change the title of this question to a more suitable title as I am not sure how to word this  question

Comment: In the first, if somebody added a value, `foo` between `one`, and `two`, then all the following values of your enum would change. In the second example, that wouldn't happen. That said, this is probably more a matter of opinion, and not really appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enum elements has names and values. It is pretty much all about *controlling* values. There are plenty of enum usages and in some of them you *care* about values.

Here are some examples:

- If you use `XmlSerializer`, then element name (text) is used to store value of a property. Here you do not care about values.
- If you save result in database, then it is less likely you going to use text field and parse, but more likely numeric field. So enum is saved as element value. This is where you care about them, because updating enum (adding new elements to it) can make already saved in database values invalid.
- If you are using *bitfields*, or if enum values are in fact grouped *constants* (enum can be used as a union of constants to group them, to example, in `iTextSharp` there are hundereds of ungrouped constants, which makes it hard to find needed one; if they would have *categories*, or enums, to hold them - it would be much more easier), then you care about values.

Actually there are known rules of how compiler assign values to enum elements. So if, to example, you had this enum

```
public enum test
{
    one,
    two,
    three
}
```

then whenever you need to add `four` and `oneandhalf` to it you can do add it like this

```
public enum test
{
    one,
    two,
    three,
    four,
    oneandhalf
}
```

or like this

```
public enum test
{
    one = 0,
    oneandhalf = 4,
    two = 1,
    three = 2,
    four = 3,
}
```

and you still keep backward compatibility (previously saved in database values are ok after update). Notice, what you have to explicitly specify values when **inserting** elements in between existing, or something [bad](http://dotnetfiddle.net/2c7T30) may happens.

Answer (score 2):

The second one is safer for serialization purposes. One example that comes to mind is WCF. In fact the serilization in WCF will throw an exception if you try to pass an object with uninitialized enum members.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure there is a canonical answer for your question but I would venture that the advantage of the second method is that if someone removes a particular value, things don't automatically renumber. In your first example, if someone removed `two`, the value of `three` would suddenly be `2`. Not so good...

Answer (score 0):

Because we can also use the second method as follows

```
public enum test2
{
    zero = 0,
    one = 5,
    two = 10,
    three = 20
}
```

so we can assign the different values with different intervals, its possible only by the second way...

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following 2 enums and you will see which one is better self-explanatory:

```
public enum numbers
{
    one = 5,
    hundred = 100,
    thousand = 1000
}
```

and

```
public enum numbers
{
    one,
    hundred,
    thousand
}
```

You can still use the second approach, but I believe you'll see what potential problems that may occur.